# Artifactory cleanup script by count of versions

Tags: groovy, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

There is [script](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup)  that deletes artifact not downloaded in specified period. But I have common necessary to keep last 10 versions (by date) of artifact and delete other versions. How to solve that issue? I need concept or code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved that issue for maven repos. It is enough for me.

1. Get all maven-metadata.xml from repo. /api/search/artifact?name=maven-metadata.xml&repos=${repo} and get uri from that json (except SPNAPSHOT one, it will be cleaned by internal artifactory retention policy), then get another json by uri and use downloadUri for download maven-metadata.xml itself.
2. Now we have groupId and artifactId and versions. Reverse list of version and use loop with index, all artifacts with index more than 10 will be deleted.